# How to change Lightswitch App language at runtime

Tags: c#, silverlight, visual-studio-lightswitch

I followed this article to create Localization inside Visual Studio LightSwitch 2012 App

[Walkthrough: Localizing a LightSwitch Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/xx130603%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Now the application would change language automatically based on the language set in the computer that running the app.

> the active Windows language pack determines which language will appear.

Is there is any way to change that at run-time by code ?

my thought is if i can set the language by code then i can have a button which switch language !

Answer (score 0):

Although not likely an answer this may give you an idea on how to implement this in LS.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=47hyerUBIag

You will most likely require a cultural specific resource file for all text within your application and then either load them all in or like in the attached video pull these resource files in asynchronously.

Cheers